# Variable showing as undefined in node.js with mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, xampp, ejs

I'm using node.js and mysql for the database. All of my webpages are in .ejs. I have 1 page for customer reviews, I have a form to POST data to my database and then show data from the database as well on the same page. I'm always getting error that a variable is undefined.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = require('./dbConfig');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

//index page
app.get('/', function (req, res,) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM reviews", function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'customers',
            revData: result
        });
    });
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.body.rname;
    var msg = req.body.rmsg;
        
    console.log(req.body);
    var sql = `INSERT INTO reviews (name, message) VALUES ("${name}", "${msg}")`;
    connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Review submitted!");
    })
    return res.render('index', { errormessage: 'insert data successfully' });
});

app.listen(process.env.port || 3000);
console.log('Running at Port 3000');
```

Here's my index.ejs page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="rev-body">
        <div class="rev-form"> <!-- Left column "Review form" -->
            <form action="/" method="POST">
                <h3>Tell us what you think!</h3>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your name here" name="rname"><br>
                <textarea placeholder="Your review here" name="rmsg" maxlength="100" id="form-textarea"></textarea><br>
                <div id="rem-char">100 / 100</div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        
        <div class="reviews"> <!-- Right column "Customer Reviews" -->
            <div class="heading" style="text-align: center"><h1>Customer Reviews</h1></div>
                <div class="review-body">
                    <% if(revData.length!=0) { var i=1; revData.forEach(function(data) {
                    %>
                    <div class="cust-comments"><p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 5px"><%=data.name %></p>
                    <p style="margin-top:0; font-size: 13px; font-style: italic">"<%=data.message %>"</p></div>
                    <% i++; }) %> <% } else { %>
                    <div><h1>No Data Found</h1></div>
                    <% } %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body></html>
```

on my index.ejs i always get an error whenever i click the submit button, BUT the data is saved on the database. besides everything else, that is the only error i get.

```
ReferenceError: C:\database\views\index.ejs:22
    20|             <div class="heading" style="text-align: center"><h1>Customer Reviews</h1></div>
    21|                 <div class="review-body">
 >> 22|                     <% if(revData.length!=0) { var i=1; revData.forEach(function(data) {
    23|                     %>
    24|                     <div class="cust-comments"><p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 5px"><%=data.name %></p>
    25|                     <p style="margin-top:0; font-size: 13px; font-style: italic">"<%=data.message %>"</p></div>

revData is not defined
    at eval ("C:\\database\\views\\index.ejs":12:8)
    at index (C:\database\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:703:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\database\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\database\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (C:\database\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\database\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (C:\database\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\database\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at C:\database\app.js:41:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\database\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

I've used all of my resources for about a week now and don't know why it's getting that error when that "revData" is already declared on the app.get

I tried declaring a variable in the ejs page with

```
<% var revData = []; %>
```

and the error goes away, but now the data does not show on the web page.
Hope someone can help me with this, this is my first time using node.js and still currently studying it.

Comment: Its because of this line **return res.render('index', { errormessage: 'insert data successfully' });** You are re rendering index on post request. you should use redirect

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean to redirect? I'm really new to node.js. I did try to remove that part and still have the same issue. thanks for replying.